# Iterate over map with index and original order in Scala template in PlayFramework2. How to pick up the one after currently iterated?

Tags: scala, dictionary, indexing, playframework-2.2

I am trying to loop over a map in scala template in playFramework2.2.
Here is the code for that:

```
<ol>
    @for(((key, value), currentIndex) <- m.myMap.zipWithIndex) {
        <li>@key - @value - @currentIndex</li>
    }
</ol>
```

map declaration in java:

```
Map myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

map declaration in scala:

```
meters: List[intranet.controllers.Index.Meter]
```

And I've sorted that map (by value) already with java method as follow:

```
public static Map sort(Map unsortMap, Order order) {     
    List list = new LinkedList(unsortMap.entrySet());


    comparator = new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
            }
        }

    Collections.sort(list, comparator);

    Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Unfortunately my problem is that I iterate over a map with `zipWithIndex` method I loose my order.

Here is current result:

```
Key - Value - Index
WA - 41 - 4
BA - 66 - 0
BM - 52 - 2
DP - 0 - 6
JTM - 0 - 7
TN - 59 - 1
WP - 46 - 3
SM - 0 - 5
```

As You can see it is not ordered, but it should be that way:

```
Key - Value - Index
BA - 66 - 0
TN - 59 - 1
BM - 52 - 2
WP - 46 - 3
WA - 41 - 4
SM - 0 - 5
DP - 0 - 6
JTM - 0 - 7
```

So question are:

1. **How to iterate over a map with index  with original order?**

I figure out first question. Here is working loop code:

```
@for(((key, value), currentIndex) <- m.lastMonthRanking.view.zipWithIndex) {
    <li>
        <span @if(session().get("email").equals(key)){ class="label label-info" style="font-size: 100%; display: grid"}>@key
            <span class="badge">@value</span>
        </span>
    </li>
}
```

2. **How to access the next/previous element after/before the one it is currently iterated?**

---

Edit

I have a map, where key is `@userName` (String) and `@value` is (Integer).
I wanna print list `<ol><li>@userName (@value)</li></ol>` ordered by `@value`. If value is repeated in many users I would like to print those element in other way, so I have to know is next/previous element in the list has the same value. Normally in java with list I would do something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CrunchifyList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(CrunchifyList.get(i-1) + " is previous element");
    System.out.println(CrunchifyList.get(i) + " is current element");
    System.out.println(CrunchifyList.get(i+1) + " is next element");
}
```

But now I need to do this in scala and with map.
Please help

Comment: Please show the full types used in the Java code and the Scala template. Further how is the Java map converted to a Scala map?

Comment: I've added what You mean I think. Please help.

Comment: Your second question is not clear. What are you really trying to achieve? It might be an instance of the XY question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for first question, you should use a map that maintains the insertion order. One example is the `scala.collection.immutable.ListMap`.

```
@ import scala.collection.immutable.{HashMap, ListMap}
import scala.collection.immutable.{HashMap, ListMap}
@ val l = 1 to 5
l: collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
@ val hm = HashMap(l.zipWithIndex: _*)
hm: HashMap[Int, Int] = Map(5 -> 4, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3)
@ val lm = ListMap(l.zipWithIndex: _*)
lm: ListMap[Int, Int] = Map(1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

@for(((key, value), currentIndex) <- m.myMap.**iterator**.zipWithIndex) {